# Awesomium.NET WebCore.CreateWebView throughs unhandled exception

Tags: awesomium

The following code throws an unhandled exception, and I have no clue why.

```
using (WebView view = WebCore.CreateWebView(1100, 600)) 
{
 ...
}
```

Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at Awesomium.Core.NativeMethods.WebCore_CreateWebView_1(HandleRef jarg1, Int32 jarg2, Int32 jarg3, HandleRef jarg4)
   at Awesomium.Core.WebCore.CreateWebView(Int32 width, Int32 height)

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

- I had the same issue and [it seems](https://github.com/awesomium/awesomium-pub/issues/12) when the JavaScript is off, it will crash. So it's better to start `WebCore.CreateWebSession` with `WebPreferences.Default` instead of `new WebPreferences` with JavaScript = false.
- Also its session needs a separate thread for the whole life of the application (just one thread and not more).